# How to access state variable located in a module whose folder name includes an hyphen?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

My store is split in modules, some of them inside folders whose name has an hyphen in it. Right now in a component I'm trying to retrieve a state variable from my "patient-data" module:

```vue
    ...mapState({
      myVariable: state => state.dashboard.patient-data.formData || {}
    })
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

Here's how my patient-data module is defined:

```vue
    modules: {
      "patient-data": {
        namespaced: true,
        ...patientDataModule
      },
      simulation: {
        namespaced: true,
        ...simulationModule
      }
    }
```

I tried to use camelCase (`state.dashboard.patientData.formData`) to no avail. Any idea?

Comment: Why not camelCase the module name instead of using a hyphen?

Comment: It's not pretty but `state.dashboard["patient-data"].formData` should work.

Comment: Don't use character's which are [invalid in JS identifiers](https://mothereff.in/js-variables#patient-data). Simple as that....

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes, thanks!! (thanks all but it's not my codebase so I can't change that)